# sass watching multiple directories

Tags: css, shell, sass, watch

What is the right way in sass to watch multiple directories from a shell script?

I have following in a shell script:

```
sass --style compressed --watch branches/mysite/assets/css/sass:branches/mysite/assets/css &
sass --style compressed --watch branches/mysite2/themes/css/sass:branches/mysite2/themes/css &
sass --style compressed --watch trunk/assets/css/sass:trunk/assets/css
```

However, this creates 3 processes and when I hit Ctrl+C to stop, not all processes are exited.

How do I get sass to watch multiple directories and exit correctly?

Comment: what about watching the folder in which all projects are included? eg. sass --style compressed --watch /var/

Comment: Because the directory where to compress the sass to css is different in each path.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'm hoping you've already tried it, but you can just add all folders into one command line:

```
sass --watch path/to/sass1:path/to/css1 path/to/sass2:path/to/css2 path/to/sass3:path/to/css3
```

Comment: I don't know why I never tried that. Thank you so much! This works perfectly!

Comment: Looks fine, especially when implemented inside a shell script

Comment: when I use command substitution (ex. `$(script that produces folders)`) the sass interprets the arguments as one `path/to/sass1` and one `path/to/css1 path/to/sass2:path/to/css2 path/to/sass3:path/to/css3` thus resulting in invalid path exception

Comment: this is pretty old. there are sufficient amount of help out there for sass/less watching. plugins come in together with frameworks etc

Comment: @mohas could you provide a complete argument to sass generated by command substition? are these indeed pairs of files split with `:` ?